# Azkaban: Failure due to too many blocked jobs in pipeline mode

Tags: bigdata, scheduler, job-scheduling, azkaban

Azkaban's pipeline mode execution results in failed jobs after a sufficient number of jobs have accumulated in the backlog. This happens if executions of a [flow](https://azkaban.github.io/azkaban/docs/latest/#creating-flows) take more time than its scheduling frequency:
[image]
Is there a way to make Azkaban launch a new instance only when the previous one has ended while at the same time not skip any instance. We cannot skip instances because the time param passed to each, helps in selecting the duration of data that has to be processed.